# Issue with remotefx with a geforce 1080

Tags: graphics-card

As seen in the picture below i am having issue using a geforce 1080 or geforce 960 graphics card with windows server 2016 virtual machine using remotefx. I was wondering if anyone here could explain why this happens when using either of the graphics cards mentioned above but seem to not be a issue with either a geforce 660 or a asus r7 240?

[image]

Comment: You are aware that RemoteFX hasn't seen an update in years, and it appears based on the glitch, there is a conflict with newer hardware and/or the driver you are using.  Are you not able to use something a better supported technology other than RemoteFX?

Comment: I need to run 10 virtual machine with windows server hyper v and due to needing graphics within the virtual machine and have directx 11. I aint really got much choice. So none of the latest graphics cards will work with remotefx ?

Comment: I am not saying that.  There is obviously a compatibility problem with the newer hardware based on the screenshot you provided.  My comment was more of an FYI type comment.

Comment: I have tested 3 different more recent geforce card 960, 1060, 1080 and found they all have the same issue. So do they all run on the same drivers and the geforce 660 run on different older drivers meaning it does not have the issue or is it something within the hardware of the newer cards causing the issue ?

Comment: ^^I'd guess that is impossible to know.

Comment: You will have to look at the driver release notes to determine which products are supported.  If the same drivers are installed when the 660 is installed and it works with it, and when the 960+ are installed, it does not work then that indicates the conflict is due to a hardware conflict not a software conflict (i.e. the drivers).  [So I thought RemoteFX development was discontinued but I was mistaken by the way.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RemoteFX#Windows_Server_2016.2C_Windows_10_Enterprise) but GPU requirements seem to be outdated.

Comment: Thanks will test that out tonight. I was told on another forum this "If I remember correctly nvidia start doing something to their gaming cards to cockblock their cards from being used in virtual environments. An attempt to force people to buy quadro or tesla series. I don't remember where I read it, but hopefully it sparks a memory in somebody with better a recollection." could this be true ?

Comment: @HarshMountain - Based on the Wikipedia it is more likely the 660 working is an bonus to be honest.  Based the GPU requirements it seems that Quadro and FirePro are required.